# ascii txt file to binary bin file

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, binary

I have a txt file with a stream of HEX data, I would like to convert it in binary fomart in order to save space on the disk.

this is my simple script just to test the decoding and the binary storage

```
hexstr = "12ab"

of = open('outputfile.bin','wb')

for i in hexstr:
    #this is how I convert an ASCII char to 7 bit representation 
    x = '{0:07b}'.format(ord(i))
    of.write(x)

of.close()
```

I exect that outputfile.bin has a size of 28 bit, instead the results is 28 byte.
I guess the problem is that x is a string and not a bit sequence.

How should I do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yep, python's `filobject.write` is expecting a string, so it probably also writes it as a string.

Comment: I think probably binascii module is what you are looking for...

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2452861/149530) question? Note that storing 7 bits for each ASCII character will only save you 1 octet every 8 characters -- possibly less depending on your file system.

Comment: What is _"a stream of HEX data"_ ? What does mean _"a txt file with a stream of HEX data"_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you will not get a file size that is not a multiple of 8 bits on any popular platform.

Second, you really have to brush up an what "binary" actually means. You confuse two different concepts: representing a number in the binary number system and writing out data in a "non human readable" form.

Actually, you are confusing two even more fundamental concepts: data and the representation of data. `"12ab"` is a representation of the four bytes in memory, as is `"\x31\x32\x61\x62"`.

Your problem is that `x` contains 28 bytes of data that can either be represented as `"0110001011001011000011100010"` or as "`\x30\x31\x31\x30\x30...\x30\x30\x31\x30"`.

Maybe this will help you:

```
>>> hexstr = "12ab"
>>> len(hexstr)
4
>>> ['"%s": %x' % (c, ord(c)) for c in hexstr]
['"1": 31', '"2": 32', '"a": 61', '"b": 62']

>>> i = 42
>>> hex(i)
'0x2a'
>>> x = '{0:07b}'.format(i)
>>> x
'0101010'
>>> [hex(ord(c)) for c in x]
['0x30', '0x31', '0x30', '0x31', '0x30', '0x31', '0x30']
>>> hex(ord('0')), hex(ord('1'))
('0x30', '0x31')

>>> import binascii
>>> [hex(ord(c)) for c in binascii.unhexlify(hexstr)]
['0x12', '0xab']
```

That said, thhe [binascii](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify) module has a method you can use:

```
import binascii

data = binascii.unhexlify(hexstr)
with open('outputfile.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

This will encode your data in 8bit instead of 7bit, but usually it is not worth the effort to use 7bit for compression reasons anyway.

Comment: thanks for your solution, it does more than what I expected! yes...I have to review 'binary' meanings

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? "12ab" should be written as `\x01\x02\x0a\x0b`, right?

```
import struct

hexstr = "12ab"

of = open('outputfile.bin','w')

for i in hexstr:
    of.write(struct.pack('B', int(i, 16)))

of.close()
```

Comment: You could also use `chr(int(i, 16))`

Comment: Actually in 7-bit encoding, `'12ab'` should be written as `\xC5\x96\x1C\x40`.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis I don't understand what you mean. A literal ``'\xC5'`` is an hexinteger (http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-and-long-integer-literals)